# Dev module reports 40-50 queries on Drupal homepage

Tags: drupal, performance

The dev module reports 40-50 queries on a Drupal installation homepage, even with few or no extra modules at all!

What do you answer to someone that says that Drupal is not optimized and has many queries that it shouldn't have?

Comment: Need more info: is caching on?  Do you have a front end (like nginx) to serve static files?  If not, are you having Drupal serve the files or are you allowing them to be accessed statically?

Comment: I'm talking about a plain-vanilla Drupal installation win caching ON. What you get when you download Drupal, make the default installation and set caching on :)

Comment: Are you logged in? Caching is mostly for anon users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default caching system solely targets anonymous users and does not improve performance for authenticated users. Authenticated users make minimal use of the cache.

Most websites tend to improve  their performance through the use of contributed caching modules and server-side mechanisms such as caching proxies, HTTP accelerators and so on. See the following URLs for more information on the caching system in Drupal as well as a list of features of commonly recommended contributed modules:

- [Caching resources](http://drupal.org/node/326504)
- [Cache module comparison](http://groups.drupal.org/node/21897)